# Extract Data from a fairly structured text file and map to XML

Tags: xml, bash, phantomjs, mapping, casperjs

I have some textual data that I scraped from an online source using CasperJS and PhantomJS. The data is fairly structured and contains a lot of unneeded data, e.g.:

```
bla bla bla text
more bla bla bla
John Smith
article
April 25 at 5:00pm · 
5 tests, 6 thumbs up, bla bla bla text

John Smith
another good article
April 25 at 6:00pm · 
3 tests, 4 thumbs-up, some more bla bla bla text
John Smith
another article
April 25 at 9:00pm · 
7 tests, 8 thumbs-up, and even more bla bla bla text

lots of bla bla bla text
```

What I need to extract is only the following fields:

1. Name, e.g. John Smith
2. Article, e.g. another article
3. Date, e.g. April 25 at 9:00pm
4. Number of tests, e.g. 7 tests
5. Number of thumbs-up, e.g. 8 thumbs-up

As obvious, they get repeated as a fixed pattern, where John Smith is a person who has many articles, each with its different attributes (article content, date, number of tests and thumbs-up). There are lots of junk around that data I need to extract to put into an XML format according to the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="author">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element ref="article" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="article">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="content" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="issueDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xs:element name="tests" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="thumbsup" type="xs:integer"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is there any way I can use bash or an xml mapper of some kind or any other utility out there to achieve that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can't you extract it directly from the DOM instead of extracting it from a textual representation? What you're trying to achieve would be very error prone.

Comment: The XHTML looks very complicated.